# Where is the final Tailwindcss file in React+Vite

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I have installed Tailwind CSS in my React + Vite project, and it is working correctly ([it's my source](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite)).

I don't know where the final Tailwind file is located (where the classes are converted to CSS code).

I expected to use a script in package.json similar to JavaScript to determine the directory of the input and output CSS files, but there is no script and no output file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `npm run dev` in your project root, access the project via the specified loacalhost url and open the browser dev tools to inspect the page. You would see the runtime css path there.

Usually, this is done automatically. Just ensure that you have imported your `./src/index.css` in your React root component (App.tsx).

Upon build `npm run build`, Vite will bundle the js and css into a build folder for you. There may be ways to control the paths but it's usually done for you automatically. As long as your css works, you're good to go!